# Simple RPG am rusty

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I want to do a small RPG program but am very rusty. It's similar to the SQL recently.

I want to read a logical file, and select only those records with todays date. The field is defined as NUmeric 8 0. YYYYMMDD
IS this the way to do this? I want to read only those records = todays date. (job date is ok ).

```
F Filename etc.

 D   Data structure for date     *** not sure how to code this,
   DS Datein
   D  year4in
       D Cent2
       D YR2
   D  month2in
   D day2in
****

D DS Dateout
D  month2out
D day2out
D  yr2out

C   Read loop 

     Read Filename until EOF.


              Move Ordhdt to Datemanip

              If Ordhdt not equal udate 

                  Leave

                       else

                            Write record to work file
                       iter
              End read loop.
```

Comment: If possible, you should look into using actual `date` types in RPG.  Other than that, define a 'global' date data-structure (and related methods - otherwise you **will** end up with February 30th) then have your RPG code import and add `likeds()` for the necessary inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fmylf   if    e              k disk

d             ds
d  now                  1   20  0
d  date                 1    8  0
d  time                 9   14  0
d  zzzzzz              15   20  0

c/free
    now = %dec(%timestamp());
    setll date mylf;
    reade date mylf;
    dow not %eof(mylf);
       // Do your processing here.
       reade date mylf;
    enddo;
    *inlr = *on;
c/end-free
```

And here's a version you may be more comfortable with:

```
FMYLF     IF   E              K DISK

DYYYYMMDD        S               8  0
D                DS
D TIME                      1    6  0
D DATE                      7   12  0
D MM                        7    8  0
D DD                        9   10  0
D YYYY                     11   14  0
D TIMEDATE                  1   14  0

C                   TIME      TIMEDATE
C                   EVAL      YYYYMMDD = (YYYY*10000) + (MM*100) + DD
C      YYYYMMDD     SETLL     MYLF
C      YYYYMMDD     READE     MYLF                                 99
C                   DOW       *IN99 = *OFF
C* Do your processing here
C      YYYYMMDD     READE     MYLF                                 99
C                   ENDDO
C                   EVAL      *INLR = *ON
```

Comment: Benny, I didn't think about free. We have there green screen, i have to see what they have. Timewise it would be faster to do greenscreen for now.

Comment: /free works perfectly in green screen, but Benny's answer can easily be downgraded to fixed format.

Comment: As Buck said, this works fine on green screens. I have included a fixed format version as well though if you're more comfortable with that.

Comment: thanks Benny, I am not sure this shop has the ability to create table like that. Using Iseries Navigator I dont see anything about database.  Only Basic operatations is installed. I need to ask them to install the others. so for now, i am stuck doing things the old way

Comment: There is no such thing as iSeries (now IBM i) without database. (Though there was, at one time, a box with yellow trim built specifically for Domino that had no DB2.) The bumble bee never really gained much traction.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the same logic with SQL using an HLL (SQLRPGLE) or [`RUNSQLSTM`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/runsqlstm.htm):

```
CREATE TABLE WORKFILE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Filename
    WHERE ORDHDT = YEAR(NOW()) * 10000 + MONTH(NOW()) * 100 + DAY(NOW())
) WITH DATA
```